# SQL Query Average last 3 days in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thank you for help in advance. Can anyone please help me with sql query for

I  have daily table like

```
    > Date        | Sales_Rep_ID| Product ID | Zone | Sales
    > 31 Jan 2015 | 001         | P01| EMEA | 10 
    > 31 Jan 2015 | 002         | P02| EMEA | 10 
    > 31 Jan 2015 | 003         | P02| EMEA | 10  
    > 30 Jan 2015 | 001         | P01| EMEA | 8 
    > 30 Jan 2015 | 002         | P02| EMEA | 7 
    > 30 Jan 2015 | 003         | P02| EMEA | 2
```

and wanted a average of last n days in last column depending upon date , rep id , product id

```
Date        | Sales_Rep_ID| Product ID | Zone | Sales | AVG_3_DAYS
31 Jan 2015 | 001         | P01        | EMEA | 10    | 9
31 Jan 2015 | 002         | P02        | EMEA | 10    | 8.5
31 Jan 2015 | 003         | P02        | EMEA | 10    | 6
30 Jan 2015 | 001         | P01        | EMEA | 8     | .
30 Jan 2015 | 002         | P02        | EMEA | 7     | .
30 Jan 2015 | 003         | P02        | EMEA | 2     | .
```

For example

for row  1 date is 31 jan and we need average for 31,30, 29 jan for sales rep 001  and product id 002

and for row 4 date is 30 jan and we need average for 30 ,29, 38 jan for sales rep 001 and product id 002

Comment: What are your researches? what did you try? Do you have a query we can revise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can use `apply` for this purpose:

```
select t.*, tt.avgsales
from t outer apply
     (select avg(sales) as avgsales
      from t t2
      where t2.rep_id = t.rep_id and
             t2.product_id = t.product_id
             t2.date <= t.date and
             t2.date > dateadd(day, -3, t.date)
     ) tt;
```

Comment: Gordon Thank you for quick response. I tried but its going in not responding mode. Is thr any other way to do it.

Comment: I would recommend an index on `t(rep_id, product_id, date)`.